# Is there any way to make this Query Selector filter for multiple tag name?

Tags: javascript, html, filter

What I'm trying to accomplish is a simple filter searchbar. I have several different divs/boxes, each containing information which is displayed with either an h1, h3, or p tag depending on the content. Initially, all of the boxes will be visible; however, when you type in text that appears in the box (or sometimes multiple boxes), every box that doesn't max will be hidden.

For example, [this is one of the boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLXXA.png). If the user were to search for any of the following, every other box would be filtered out (unless they shared text).

- Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition
- Let's Play Baldur's Gate EE Co-Op (2013)
- Arandor (Human Priest)
- Roleplaying Game

The searchbar also accepts partial text (so even if you just typed in "baldur", it would still work).

---

Alright, now that we have that out of the way, let's get to the problem. Right now, the script attached to this searchbar **will only filter out h1 tags.** This is presumably because in the code below h1 comes first. Speaking of which, here's the script.

```
function searchLp() {
    let input = document.getElementById('search-lp').value;
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.querySelectorAll('.bigger');
    x.forEach((item) => {   
        if((!item.querySelector("h1").innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input))) {
            item.classList.add('hidden');
        } else {
            item.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    })
}
```

I've also tried the following, with no success.

1. Using or (||) in the if statement to include all of the possible tags.
2. Adding all of the tags into the querySelector (i.e. querySelector("h1, h3, p").
3. Using querySelectorAll with all three tags. This does the same as above - only h1 works.
4. Altering the code to check the innerHTML (innerHTML.includes(..)) of the item entirely, not just the tags selected.

In the end, it's not catastrophic if you can only search for the game titles (that is, the h1 tags). But I'd prefer to be able to search by game title, series title, character name and genre if possible.

Comment: Instead of searching in `innerHTML` of the elements, you probably have an array that you use to render the boxes, so create a filtered array on input change and use the filtered array to render filtered boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll("p, h1, h3")` to get all those elements, and `Array.prototype.some()` to test if any of them contain the search text.

```
function searchLp() {
  let input = document.getElementById('search-lp').value;
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.bigger');
  x.forEach((item) => {
    let fields = [...item.querySelectorAll("h1,h3,p")];
    if (fields.some(el => el.innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input)) _ {
        item.classList.add('hidden');
      } else {
        item.classList.remove('hidden');
      }
    }
  });
}
```